# Google Apps Script - Converting column of data into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I have a program that works as below

```
function test() {
var urls = [
    'URL1, 
    'URL2',
    'URL3'
  ]

var results = xx(urls)
```

^and then xx works its magic and produces results.

Now I want to input the urls via a column in a spreadsheet instead of hard coding them into the script, and so I tried

```
 function test() {
    var urls = []
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Input")
    urls[0] = ss.getRange(2, 1, ss.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues().join()
    
    var results = xx(urls)
```

But the result is that only one of the URLs gets processed.

Answer (score 3):

**Explanation:**

You haven't provided what this magical `xx` function does, but according to the first code snippet, `xx` accepts a single array of elements.

Therefore, one way of going from `2D` array to `1D` is to use [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

**Solution:**

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Input")
  const urls = ss.getRange(2, 1, ss.getLastRow()-1).getValues().flat(); // 1D array
  const results = xx(urls);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply!

Unfortunately flat() doesn't seem to work with Google apps scripts?

Comment: @user10553622 enable v8 environment and it will work..... Google on how to enable v8 environment : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the most elegant solution, but got it to work by modifying it:

```
function test() {
var urls = {}
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Input")
urls = ss.getRange(2, 1, ss.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
urls = [].concat.apply([], urls)

var results = xx(urls)
```